# How to register our application in iphone appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store

I m new in iphone development.can anyone tall me How to register our application in iphone appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to register as an apple developer account at http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/.